# How to have more than one include in org babel?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am working with C++ in org babel and would like to know how to format the includes so that I can list more than one.

Here's what I'm trying (that fails)

```
#+BEGIN_SRC C++ :includes <cstdio> :includes <iostream> :includes <string>
using namespace std;
printf("Hello ");
cout << "world\n";
#+END_SRC
```

In this case both `printf` and `cout` are undeclared in this scope. I can drop the unnecessary `:includes <string>` from the headers and the `cout` doesn't kick up an error, so it seems like only the last `:includes` counts. I have tried loading multiple includes into the same line using nothing, commas and spaces as delimiters and I always get an error about extra tokens at the end of the include directive. I have also tried using `:includes+` in case that worked on the header line, but it didn't.

I'm fairly certain that what I'm trying to do should be possible because it says in [the documentation that](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C.html)

```
:includes
(C & CC+ only) accepts either a single string name, or a list of names of files to #include in the execution of the code block
```

Org-version: 8.2.7-4-g880362-elpa

EDIT:

It's worth noting that other header arguments can just be strung together (i.e. `:results raw drawer` will produce unformatted results in a drawer), so there's a decent chance that this is a bug. Using `:include <cstdio> <iostream>` produces a compiler error that there's an extra token at the end of the `#include <cstdio>` line.

EDIT 2:

Turns out it's actually a bug in org, so it's been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, during which I noticed that some error messages look fairly lispy, and using the superficial knowledge I have of Lisp, I found the answer:

```
#+begin_src C++ :includes '("<math.h>" "<iostream>" "<algorithm>")
// Freely use symbols from those headers
#+end_src
```

Another issue that I'm having is that I can only get it to execute if I capitalize C++ but I only get syntax highlighting if I use minuscules ("c++").  Pure joy.